# Not login in magento2 frontend and it not give any error help me for that

Tags: magento2

I am a beginner in Magento I Download magento 2 with sample data community version 
On front end I sig-in then it works and when i login on the frontend with same credentials it doesnot work?

Comment: Is your domain name localhost? Please do not use localhost as domain name. see alankent.me/2015/04/25/use-of-localhost-when-installing-magento-2-quick-note/

Comment: not give error.. could be a javascript error since errors are loaded via js.